# Atom editor with Azerty Keyboard : which keys to fold/unfold lines?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor, azerty-keyboard

With Atom Editor, on a Qwerty Keyboard, the combination `Shift + Ctrl + Alt + [`  allows you to fold all identation, and `Shift + Ctrl + Alt + [` to unfold.

This combination is impossible on an Azerty Keyboard as `[` can only be accessed with the `AltGr` key which cannot be used along with `Alt` Key.

Do you know how to fold/unfold lines in Atom Editor on an Azerty Keyboard ?

Answer (score 0):

The Atom Flight Manual includes instructions on [how to set new keybindings](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#customizing-keybindings). Atom doesn't have an ability to distinguish between keyboards as far as I know, so if a character like `[` is inaccessible with the rest of the keybinding, then you should definitely define your own.

Comment: Thank you @Holland Wilson. I'll try and come back.